# Is it possible to list scriptmethods alone in vscode powershell plugin?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

With Ctrl+Shift+O i am able to see the list of function names in vscode.

But our module mostly has scriptmethods as below.

```
$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod Testcase_1 {

}
.
.
.
$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod Testcase_10 {

}
```

Is there any short cut way to find only the scriptmethods? Or is there any way we can search a particular string using some keybinding? So that I can add 'Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod' with that keybinding and find them?

Comment: `$Object | Get-Member -MemberType Method` (or `ScriptMethod`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 ScriptMethod

Comment: I was answering your question: Is there any short cut way to find only the scriptmethods?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 In vscode , if Ctrl+shift+o is pressed ,it will list the function name. I am asking whether any short cut like that present.

Comment: You can probably create a keybind that calls `Get-Variable` on an entry you specify and then calls `| Get-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod` on it